# Changing the formatting of the Theorem and Proof environment

Tags: environments, proof-package, definition

I ask the question directly in the code.

```
       \documentclass[
          11pt,
        ]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
        
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
        \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
        \usepackage{bbding}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{thmtools}
        
        \declaretheorem[
          style=plain,
          name=Theorem,    % How can I write a dot (".") after the number of the Theorem?
          ]{thm}
        \declaretheorem[
          style=plain,
          name=Lemma,
          numberlike=thm,
        ]{lem}
        \declaretheorem[
              style=plain,    % See below how the environment should behave
              name=Proof,
              numberlike=thm,
            ]{proof}
        
        
        \begin{document}
        \chapter{Title}
        \begin{thm}
        A proposition.
        \end{prop}
        \begin{lem}\label{L1}
        A lemma.
        \end{lem}
        \begin{thm}
        A theorem.
        \end{thm}
    
    \begin{proof}{Proof of Lemma~\ref{L1}}   % How can I get the proof environment such that 
%"Proof of Lemma 1" is written in the same style as Theorem 1 and lemma 1 before?
    A proof.
    \end{proof}
        
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure why you use both `amsthm` and `thmtools`, refer the documentation of `amsthm`, it's so much easy to understand....

Comment: Hi Madyyuvi, I used both packages just because this was used in an example which I found on my search to answer my question. I now had a look athe documentation and I did not find something on changing the fontsize.

Comment: @MadyYuvi `thmtools` is an add-on and works best if `amsthm` is loaded.

Comment: Thx MadyYuvi: Do you have an idea how I get my Proof environment? I am unable to deduct a solution from the documentation.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your tips...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're referring to with the “dot after the number”, because it appears.

In order to modify the font used in the header for proofs, one should either wait for the AMS to issue a new version of `amsthm` with the promised hook or patch it. The presence of `thmtools` makes the patch a bit adventurous, but, trust me, it works.

Note that for a “named proof” you should use the optional argument.

Note also that for some years `scrbook` hasn't get along with `classicthesis` and support for the `titlesec` package the latter is using might be dropped altogether without notice. Better going with `book`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Theorem,
]{thm}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Lemma,
  numberlike=thm,
]{lem}

\makeatletter
%% unfortunately, thmtools juggles with \proof
\let\proof\thmt@original@proof
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\let\thmt@original@proof\proof
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}

\begin{thm}
A proposition.
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{L1}
A lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
A standard proof.
\end{proof}
    
\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma~\ref{L1}]
A named proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]